# Javascript if function only checks for one variable despite ||

Tags: javascript, html, validation, if-statement, boolean

I am using php, javascript and html to create a website where logged in users can comment in a chatbox. I am trying validate the input email during account creation by checking if it includes '@' and '.'. The call to the function is within an html file. The form (wrapper and body excluded looks like this:

```
<form id="form" onsubmit="HandleSubmit(event)" action="accountcreation.php" method="POST">
                 
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" required>
    <br>
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" required>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button type="submit">Create account</button>
            
    </form>
```

The function is being called below:

```
<script src="validate.js"></script>
<script>
    function HandleSubmit(e) {
        console.log("OnSubmit");

        // Validation
        if (!ValidateEmail("email")) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("Invalid input of email");
            return false;
        }

    }
</script>
```

In the validate.js file the function is contructed like this:

```
function ValidateEmail(emailinputId) {

    const elem = document.getElementById(emailinputId);
    if ( !elem.value.includes(".") || !elem.value.includes("@")) {
        return false;
    }
    
    return true;

}
```

The webpage only sends and alert when the '@' sign is missing but is fine with '.' missing.
I need to solve this within a day so I'm praying for a saviour.

I have tried with both && and || which didn't work.
I tried separating the '.' and '@' checks into separate if statements within the same function which didn't work.

I changed it to an alternate version:

```
function ValidateEmail(emailinputId) {

    const elem = document.getElementById(emailinputId);
    
    if ( ("." in elem ) && ("@" in elem)) {
        return true;
    }
    
    return false;

}
```

And called to it in the same way.

Same thing happens. What is the issue?

Comment: The version with `||` reject inputs like `a@a` or `a.a` but accepts `a@a.a`. However, you may need to clear the cache (your browser may still be using an older version)

Comment: Yes! It was the cache thankfully. The function works the way I imagined it would now. Unfortunately things like aa.a@ is a valid email though. If you spare the time and have any simple tips for a better format, that would be appreciated. I saw something with regular expressions but it seemed a bit more advanced than what I'm doing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're experiencing lies within your usage of the logical operators in your condition. In your first `ValidateEmail` function, you're using the AND operator (&&), meaning both conditions have to be false to return false. So if any of the characters (either "." or "@") is present, it would return true which is not the behavior you want.

Here's a modified version of your function:

```js
function ValidateEmail(emailinputId) {
  const elem = document.getElementById(emailinputId);
  
  return elem.value.includes(".") && elem.value.includes("@");
}

function HandleSubmit(e) {
  console.log("OnSubmit");

  // Validation
  if (!ValidateEmail("email")) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Invalid input of email");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="form" onsubmit="HandleSubmit(event)" action="accountcreation.php" method="POST">

  <label for="email">Email:</label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email" required>
  <br>
  <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <br>
  <input type="password" name="password" required>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button type="submit">Create account</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I got confused on the operators. I might be misinterpreting what you're saying but; when I implemented your code, the same issue remains. No '@' spawns the alert but if the input email includes '@' while not including '.' the account is still created and the code continues to "accountcreation.php".

Comment: I've revised my response for you. You could consider removing the `onClick` event handler from the submit button and then giving it another attempt.